# How to select data with a certain minimum total?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have one table `bbc(country, region, area, population, gdp)`.

I want to select the regions with a total population of at least 100 million. How can I do it with SQL?

Comment: @Dharmendra As you have noticed, most of your questions have been closed. Please see this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language. It has links that may help you.

Comment: This answer in particular is very useful in *all* cases. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language/15311#15311

Comment: you are a good guy devin.....

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT
    country,
    region,
    SUM(population)
FROM
    bbc
GROUP BY
    country,
    region
HAVING
    SUM(population) >= 100000000
```

Comment: +1 for grouping by `country, region`. Good thinking ahead there.

Answer (score 3):

```
select region, sum(population) as population from bbc 
         group by region 
         having sum(population) >= 100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for Salil's answer, but don't have the reputation just yet . :)

His query returns the regions where the sum of countries populations total more or equal than 100 million.

The first answer is grouped by country and region, so it returns the **countries and regions** where the population in a country is greater or equal than 100 mil.

So the first answer misses the case when all countries in a region have < 100 mil population each, but >= 100 mil together.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT region FROM bbc GROUP BY region HAVING `SUM(population) >= 100000000`
```